# CSS issue with a gap from float property

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm still fairly new to CSS and the combination of properties and I'm having an issue where a gap has appeared that I don't want. After playing around with the properties and watching a few youtube vids I'm still having issues. The spacing should be 10 pixels from the bottom of the Welcome Tile to the Example Title.

I'm attempting to make a tile similar to to Windows Metro, or whatever they are calling it. I've created anchor ID's and the CSS for the ID's creates the tiles.

This image shows the problem:

[image]

```
.header {   
    background:url(../images/header2.png) no-repeat;
    width:384px;    
    height:69px; 
}

#content {  
    position:relative;  
    width:384px;    
    height:646px;   
    margin-top:30px;    
    overflow:hidden;    
    border:none;
    background-color:#CCC; 
}

.welcomeTile {  
    background:url(../images/welcomeTile.jpg) no-repeat;    
    float:left;
    width:180px;    
    height:280px;   
    margin-left:7px; 
}

.aboutTile{     
    background:url(../images/aboutTile.jpg) no-repeat;
    float:left;     
    width:180px;    
    height:105px;   
    margin-left:10px; 
}

.galleryTile{       
    background:url(../images/galleryTile.jpg) no-repeat;
    float:left;     
    width:180px;    
    height:105px;   
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px; 
}

.examplesTile{      
    background:url(../images/examplesTile.jpg) no-repeat;
    float:left;     
    width:180px;    
    height:105px;   
    margin-left:7px;
    clear:left; 
}

.contactTile{       
    background:url(../images/contactTile.jpg) no-repeat;
    float:left;     
    width:180px;    
    height:105px;   
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:7px;    
    clear:left; 
}
```

Comment: seems like the height you've assigned to the welcome tile is too big...

Comment: How about you add the html code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be bad math calculations..

The `.aboutTile` and the `.galleryTile` both have `105px` height and a `10px` margin between them.
That is a total of `220px` but the `.welcomeTile` has `280px` height.

That leave 60 more pixels that go to the bottom.

If you wanted 10 pixels distance from the `.examplesTile` you should set the `.welcomeTile` to have `230px`.
Or better yet to have `220px` height and a `10px` bottom margin.

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/mCB25/

Comment: Yep, it was. And the annoying thing is, I had already fixed that and must of xtrl+z'ed it back without noticing.

Thank you so much! Can't believe I missed it =/

Answer (score 0):

When working with CSS Style sheets,, when you have more than two tiles stacked the lowest two in a stack of three or the two too the right side of the three will follow the first one,,, you will have to adjust using a negative number on your height,,all other tiles will follow the first one.. if you move the first one at top all will follow it,,,now in reverse if you move a middle one the top will move also,,and if you move the bottom or far left one, the middle one will move also,,,so you compensate with Negative numbers on your Height. If this helps,,lol Hard to explain.